# How to combine only given rows in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I know pandas can automatically join rows and get the sum of the rows using `groupby()` function. But how to combine two or more rows which don't have common values. Consider the following example data set.

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0 11   13   5.5   0.9
1 14   6    3.1   0.7
2 18   7    5.5   0.1
3 9    2    7.0   0.2
4 17   10   2.3   1.1
5 15   3    6.9   2.7
6 11   4    3.5   2.9
7 13   11   4.6   0.2
```

Let's say I want to combine rows 3,4 adding the values together (sum) and also combine rows 6,7 same way separately (i.e. sum). How can I achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum specific rows, you can use `df.iloc`:

```
res1 = df.iloc[[3, 4], :].sum()

# Col1    26.0
# Col2    12.0
# Col3     9.3
# Col4     1.3
# dtype: float64

res2 = df.iloc[[6, 7], :].sum()

# Col1    24.0
# Col2    15.0
# Col3     8.1
# Col4     3.1
# dtype: float64
```

If you want to "combine" them, i.e. remove original rows and add new ones, then you use `df.append`:

```
df = df.drop([3, 4, 6, 7], axis=0)\
       .append(res1, ignore_index=True)\
       .append(res2, ignore_index=True)

#    Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
# 0  11.0  13.0   5.5   0.9
# 1  14.0   6.0   3.1   0.7
# 2  18.0   7.0   5.5   0.1
# 3  15.0   3.0   6.9   2.7
# 4  26.0  12.0   9.3   1.3
# 5  24.0  15.0   8.1   3.1
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp. This is what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
#create empty columns. You could also replace the original columns

row['sum1'] = np.nan
row['sum2'] = np.nan  
def sum_rows(row):
    row['sum1'] = row['Col3'] + row['Col4']
    row['sum2'] = row['Col5'] + row['Col6']
    return row
df = df.apply(sum_rows,axis=1)
```

This is a quick way to do it.

Comment: Does the axis=1 signal that I want to add rows together? What is col 4,5 and 6? I need to add rows together by summing columns together

Comment: `axis=1`  tells `DataFrame.apply` to work by row; otherwise it would work by columns. rows here are added un the `sum_rows` function

Comment: I'm little confused with having `row['sum1']` and `row['sum2']`. The resulting row of the combine should have same no. of columns but contains values of the sum of each columns added.

Comment: What you describe just needs a little more manipulation... however, if you sum two columns, (3, 4) then sum 2 more columns (5,6) , which column do you want to replace? And the result wouldn't have the same shape, as you would now have 2 less columns. Once you have your summed rows, you can manipulate the dataframe however you'd like.